# Connection already open error c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect to an online database via SSH tunnel program.

I wrote an update function to truncate the existing table and call the Insert() method inside the 'update' class.

```
    public void Update()
        {
            string connStr = "server=localhost;port=3306;database=domian_db;user=domain_user;password=pass123";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

          conn.Open();

      if (this.OpenConnection() == true) ** Error triggered line
{



       string query = "TRUNCATE TABLE data_table";



MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

       Insert();      
       conn.Close();
         }
 }
```

I do have a function named 'OpenConnection' and the error refers to this function.

```
 private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("MySQL connected.");
            return true;
        }
catch{//I am not mentioning the code inside for the sake of space}
      }
```

In the halfway of the execution, there's an error message popping up stating,

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection is already open.' "

Any clue regarding this error?

Comment: you have `conn.Open();` and `connection.Open();` in `OpenConnection `, hence, you're trying to open another connection by calling `OpenConnection` after the connection is already opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the connection twice indeed (2 calls to Open() method). You need to check the state of the connection using something similar to :

```
connection.State == ConnectionState.Open
```

Comment: I've included your condition inside the if statement instead of "this.OpenConnection() == true" and now it's working. @PmanAce